# Use of setter and Object.create();

Tags: javascript, prototype, setter

I'm currently reading the series of books **You don't know JS**. In one of the books it's written :

> If a foo is found higher on the [[Prototype]] chain and it’s a setter
>   (see Chapter 3), then the setter will always be called. No foo will be
>   added to (aka shadowed on) myObject, nor will the foo setter be
>   redefined.

Now I tried the following code:

```
var a = {
  set t(tet) {
    this._t_ = tet;
  },
  get t() {
    return this._t_ ;
  }
};

a.t = 5;
var b = Object.create(a);
b.t = 4;
console.log(a.t);
console.log(b.t);
```

For my suprise the logs print out `5` and `4` in that order. From what is written in the book I expect to see two `4` being printed, but it seems there is actually shadowing. Why is that ?

---

Thanks to the answer by Quentin, this is actually the code that demonstrates the functionallity I wanted :)

```
var a = { 
  t : undefined, 
  set t(tet) {
    t = tet;
  },
  get t() {
    return  t ;
  }
};

a.t = 5;
var b = Object.create(a);
b.t = 4;
console.log(a.t);
console.log(b.t);
```

Comment: You should drop that `t : undefined,`, it's invalid in ES5. And you should instead declare the global variable `t` that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `4` and `5` are stored in `_t_` on the two different objects, not in `t`.

`t` is still the setter and getter in both cases (although the value of `this` varies because it is called in the context of two different objects).

Comment: Thanks :) . How  can then I change the value in `a` if I wanted to do that thru `b`. Is there a way using the setter ?

Comment: Use a variable instead of a property of the current object.

Comment: Ok thanks. One last question -  where can I find an example where the rule with the setter is actually used ?

Comment: @user3719857 — It's actually used in this example. You set `b.t = 4` and it calls the setting function higher up the prototype chain instead of just masking it and setting the `t` property to `4`.